# EPSG:25833 in LeafletJs

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, wms, proj4js, projection-mathematics

I am currently working on the different coordinate system. 
Specifically, I am concerned with the correct presentation of EPSG:25833 (ETRS89/UTMZone89) in Leaflet.

If I am right Leaflet used as default this system:

https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/

As an example I use this WMS Server https://www.orka-mv.de/geodienste/orkamv/wms?version=1.3.0&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities that uses this system:

https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/25833/

I had a look to Proj4Leaflet (https://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/) that makes it possible to use projections and CRS not built into Leaflet. All major projections (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) are supported by Proj4Leaflet.

Then I created a WMS layer without projection and in Leaflet everything looks OK. This is my code:

```
var testlayer = L.tileLayer.wms("https://www.orka-mv.de/geodienste/orkamv/wms?version%3D1.3.0%26", {
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.6,
    layers: 'orkamv',
    attribution: "todo"
}).addTo(map);
```

I then looked at the exact differences and found that the "difference/error" is less than 1 meter.

I think about whether the effort of a projection for display is worthwhile.

But, it is important for me to output the coordinates correctly. I think I can do that by converting the standard Leaflet coordinates (for example, 53.22 12.18) into my format (for example, 347560 5922583) using a formula.
If I see that correctly, I must also exchange `lat` and `lon`

**My question: Whats the best way to convert EPSG:25833 to WGS:84 in Leaflet? Is there something I can rely on or need to reinvent the wheel myself**

Comment: Please ask only one question per `question`

Comment: @nmtoken Know there is only one question.

Comment: What gives you the impression, that UTM 33 N is no major projection, or rather part of a major projection family?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to convert a layer from a service from epsg:25833  to epsg:4326 in Leaflet, when the service will give you the layer in epsg:4326

Comment: what if you add `crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,` to your ` L.tileLayer.wms(...` code

Comment: @Erik
You asked: "What gives you the impression, that UTM 33 N is no major projection, or rather part of a major projection family".

I have this expression because Proj4Leaflet wrote on the page http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/, that Proj4Js supports all major projections. But Proj4JS did not define a global variable for EPSG:25833:
https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/blob/master/lib/global.js

Comment: @nmtoken It is for learning reasons.
But you are right. I was sure, that the service offers only epsg:25833, because the url in qgis for the layer properties starts with "crs=EPSG:25833"

Now I took a close look at the capabilities file and found that many coordinate systems are provided.
So, how do I know which coordinate systems Leaflet uses

Comment: By default Leaflet uses EPSG:3857

Comment: Thank you very much. I have now found out myself. Leafletjs is smart enough to pick a coordinate system that supports it. I thought that I can influence this. But it is probably like this: Only if no supported system is offered, an error is displayed. With
’’’
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:25833',
'+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
{
resolutions: [ 8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1,0.5],
origin: [0, 0]
})
var nticwsmmap = L.map("nticwsmmap", {crs: crs});
’’’
I can set the correct coordinate system for EPSG:25833.